# Getting File one (have two classes and functions) elements in file two in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a file (PatchFinder.py) with two classes:

```
class PatchFinder():
    
  def __init__(self, dataset, pf: float):
        #super(TopFeatures, self).__init__()
        self.pf = pf
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.datas = dataset[0].to('cpu')

    def TopFeaturesFind(self, g: Graph) -> Graph:
        Zxx, self.edge_index_, edge_weights = g.unfold()
        print(self.pf)
        print(Zxx)
        print(self.edge_index_)
        print(edge_weights)
        return Zxx
    def anotherMethod(self):
        print("something")
```

2nd class

```
 class Class2(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dataset, hidden_channels):
        super(GCN, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x, edge_index_):
        return x
```

Now in another File2.py I want to get the `TopFeaturesFind()` values. This is what i am doing:

```
import PatchFinder
def main():
    tf = PatchFinder()
    t=tf.TopFeaturesFind()
    print(t)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but i am getting error:

```
    tf = PatchFinder()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What I am doing wrong here? I am from a java background. This seems ok to me. As far as i read

As stated: “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. [source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

Note: I don't want to inherit the `PatchFinder`, both files are in the same folder.

Comment: To access the `PatchFinder` class within `File2.py` you will have to use `tf = PatchFinder.PatchFinder()`. That will probably fail with a `TypeError` saying that `__init__` is expecting arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `import PatchFinder` imports the *module*, so when you call `PatchFinder()` you are trying to "initialise" the module, not the class.  There's guidance here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

All you need to do is specify that you want to initialise the object defined within the module.  Change `tf = PatchFinder()` to `tf = PatchFinder.PatchFinder()` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

PatchFinder is the module that you are calling. To access the PatchFinder class
USE

```
tf = PatchFinder.PatchFinder()
```

OR import the class like this

```
from PatchFinder import PatchFinder
```